# I would like to If file upload failure after retry to another url

Tags: fine-uploader

I have multiple vaults in diff location 1.Upload1.abc.com 2.upload2.abc.com. I would like to post at Upload1.abc.com if the file fails to upload it will start the whole process again to post file to Upload2.abc.com

so that the file upload doesn't fail.Even if one chunk fails again the whole set is uploaded to the next fallback url on runtime.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly an interesting way to handle failed uploads. There is no way to ensure `1.Upload1.abc.com` is always up?

I would react to the [`complete`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#complete) event thrown by Fine Uploader. If the `responseJSON` has a `success` property that is *not* `true` then pop  a new endpoint of the endpoints stack, issue a [`setEndpoint`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html) call, and finally issue a `retry` call so the upload restarts like so,

```js
var original_endpoints = ['1.Upload1.abc.com', '2.upload2.abc.com']
  , endpoints = original_endpoints;

var fu = new qq.FineUploader({
  // ... Other options
  cors: { 
    expected: true // this *must* be a cross-origin request
  },
  request: {
    endpoint: endpoints.shift() // the original endpoint to be attempted first
   },
  callbacks: {
    onComplete: function (fileId, fileName, responseJSON, xhr) {
        if (responseJSON.success != true) {
          var endpoint = endpoints.shift();
          if (endpoint !== undefined) {
            // Changes endpoint for *all* subsequent uploads
            this.setEndpoint(endpoint); 

            // Or, to change the endpoint for this particular file that failed
            // and try the original endpoint again on the next file,
            // this.setEndpoint(endpoints, fileId);
          } else {
            // This will restart the process by setting the endpoints queue to 
            // its default. Note that you may want to handle the error of all
            // endpoints failing another way, as this just restarts the process
            // and may result in an infinite loop if all endpoints are constantly down.
            endpoints = original_endpoints;
            this.setEndpoint(endpoints.shift());
          }

          this.retry(fileId); // Retry the upload

        }   
    }
  }
});
```